# What criteria based on expressing standard rate of reaction?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

When given the reaction: $\ce{NO2}$ reacts with $\ce{O2}$ to produce $\ce{N2O5}$, how do I calculate the rate of consumption of $\ce{NO2}$ when the rate of the reaction= 0.02 M/s?

I am confused  about which of these  expressions of reaction rate  can be used to calculate the rate of consumption of $\ce{NO2}$.

**a )   r = 0.02 = (1/4) ×  rate of consumption of $\ce{NO2}$**

Or :

**b)    r = 0.02 = (1/2) ×  rate of consumption of $\ce{NO2}$**

Does the rate of the reaction changed when we multiply balanced reaction equation by integer? Why?

Comment: I think a good starting point would be to write out the balanced equation for NO2 plus O2 to N2O5.

Comment: @airhuff :what happens to the rate of reaction  on doubling the stoichiometry of the equation at constant concentrations?

Comment: To your first comment: your equation has 4 N's on the left and 8 on the right; not balanced.  While there are an infinite number of balanced equations, what you want is the lowest factors.  Hint: 4NO2 is a good start but the number of O2 and N2O5 molecules are incorrect. This is necessary to know to figure out how much NO2 is consumed per N2O5 produced.

Comment: @airhuff :thank you : We can start with many multiplication of the balanced equation like this :8NO2 +2 O2 -----> 4N2O5 , how to calculate the rate of consumption of NO2?Does it change when  doubling the stoichiometry of the equation?